# Why are there no simple, cross-platform, C/C++ GUI tookits for higher level languages?

Tags: python, user-interface

I have a little programming experience and I did get to work with Swing (Java) and wxPython. 
Some years ago, I ended up having to port an app I did to OS X and all the problems I've had with wxPython just multiplied. I've started looking at alternatives and I could not find anything better than wxPython. QT was the only one that came even close. GTK was hell on Windows (last time I checked).

I don't think my predicament is unique, some other people might have reached the same position over the years.

So, why isn't there a GUI toolkit to have the following characteristics:

1. Simple. Basic windows/dialogs (native open and save) + a basic set of widgets with SOLID Layout management. Additional (composite widgets) implemented as additional libraries.
2. Actively maintained on OS X, Linux and Windows
3. Actively maintained bindings to at least 3 high level languages.
4. Actively maintained documentation for best practices GUI devel with examples using the toolkit. MVC/MVP properly explained. GUI HIG (Apple style) simply explained, complete with semantics, paradigms, best practices, alignment, proper spacing and TONS of best of their kind examples from successful pieces of software.
5. A simple way of building a distributable executable for the 3 targeted platforms in each of the languages.
6. Implemented as close to the metal using readily available libs like Clutter, cairo, etc.

Are these requirements too much to ask? If yes, why?

Help me understand why isn't there such a tiny lib available?

Comment: 7. Should provide the moon on a stick.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried `Qt`? It is a cross platform `C++` GUI toolkit for higher level language (`PyQt`). And it seemed very simple to me.

Comment: I remember that at some point, Qt on Windows looked horrific. Is it now okay?

Comment: Qt now uses native widgets, so it looks a LOT nicer than it used to.

Comment: Qt doesn't use native widgets (afaik), but it never looked or felt non-native for me. A whole lot of programs use Qt.

Comment: These days, Qt is actually one of the toolkits that tries the hardest to use native widgets whenever they're available. Of course, some of the components don't *have* native equivalents, so Qt has to build them out of smaller elements. And compared to wxwidgets, it presents a far cleaner abstraction layer to the application programmer.

Comment: I've looked on QT and indeed it is the closest but still, not good enough. I loved the signals-slots. QT is not simple enough. It is still huge. The pyQT bindings are very good but, with the advent of pySide, they seam doomed somehow.

Answer (score 2):

What you ask is a simple lib with enormous flexibility. Be able to build 3 * 3 executables, having good documentation and using other libraries all with a different background. And all of that on different OS platforms. It is quite a challenge it think QT would com the closest but it does not meet all your criteria.

Comment: True, QT comes close. I do realize that it is quite a challenge but it is still feasible for a small team in my view. The [Shoes platform](http://shoesrb.com/) was created by ONE man (_why). It doesn't do what I require but it is a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

[SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/)? You can use it from Java, Python (well, Jython), Ruby (well, JRuby), Groovy, LISP (well, Clojure), and anything else that runs on the JVM.

It's simple-ish, it uses native widgets under the hood, it's actively maintained, and because you're distributing either a JAR or a JAR and some interpretable code, there's a unified build process. I can comment on its documentation, nor its proximity to any sort of metal.

I recognize that this is probably not the answer you were looking for.

Comment: SWT is nice from an API point of view but it is not small and certainly not close to the metal. Think about producing an self-contained app for windows or OS X that will be developed on python or ruby and will not rely on external libraries. Considering what will have to include, it will be HUGE (by my standard).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that windows developers couldn't be bothered as they have wpf etc and linux developers couldn't be bothered as they are used to it. So only people who are sick of win developement and moving to linux would embrace it. Maybe its time for you to start an open source project :) I was thinking something like wpf but based on opengl would be a good start.

Comment: you a actually touched a very important part of the issue. Each set of developers have their toolkit that works beautifully on their system. It is very well integrated. However, the problem is that more and more there is a need for cross-platform. Now even more than 5 years ago because of a combined rise in both OS X and Linux.

Comment: As to the "start my own", I lack low level knowledge of the 3 platforms. I also lack knowledge of C/C++. I could reasonably get involved with the high level languages demos but for that I would have to have the foundation.

Answer (score 0):

The Tk toolkit meets most of your requirements, except maybe for number four. It's very cross-platform, uses native widgets when possible, is easy to use, etc. The requirement for distribution is hard to meet because that depends on the language, but when used with tcl, you can use tclkits and starkits which are an absolutely fantastic way to distribute code (essentially, your single-file executable has an embedded virtual file system that can contain all your assets -- code, images, etc).

For more on the cross language, cross-platform features of tk see http://www.tkdocs.com

Comment: I'll take another look at Tk. I remember the canvas being very powerful.

Comment: The canvas, and also the text editor. I've been working lately with wxPython and the styled text control, and with all its bells and whistles I still much prefer the text widget.

Answer (score 0):

[WXWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) seems a good fit as well.